# How do I randomly generate data that is distributed according to my own density function in R?

Tags: r, statistics, probability

I'm looking for a method that lets me randomly generate data according to my own pre-defined [Probability density function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VF3Ul.png)

Is there a method that lets me do that? Or at least one that generates data according to this specific function?

Comment: The `sample()` function can do that if it's a discrete distribution, as yours looks to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your own pre-defined pdf has $y \in {0, 1}$, the pdf is the pdf of a Bernoulli distribution with parameter $\pi$.
Using that a Bernoulli random variable corresponds to a Binomial with number of trials equal to 1 ($n=1$), you can draw from the pdf using the following code:

```
pi <- 0.5 
n <- 10 # Number of draws from specified pdf 
draws <- rbinom(n, 1, pi) # Bernoulli corresponds to Binom with `size = 1`
print(draws) 
# Outputs: [1] 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1
```